# Load jQuery twice HTML

Tags: javascript

I need your help, I insert two jQuery files for my welcome page :

webflow.js
detheme.js

I have this error :

```
jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: e is not a function
at r.define (detheme.js:7)
at O (webflow.js:7)
at Object.t.each.t.forEach (webflow.js:38)
at HTMLDocument.r.ready (webflow.js:7)
at l (VM13721 jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
at c (VM13721 jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
```

I think there is a conflict between JavaScript files, no error when I load one of them. I don't know how to fix it.

Calling from html :

```
<html>
<head>
...
</head>
<html>
<body>
.....
<script src="https://d1tdp7z6w94jbb.cloudfront.net/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="js/detheme.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/webflow.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help :(

Comment: Why are you adding this line in twice ? <script src="https://d1tdp7z6w94jbb.cloudfront.net/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 pretty sure you only need it once

Comment: you are adding jquery library 2 times that's the reason

Comment: jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: e is not a function TypeError: e is not a function
    at r.define (http://localhost:51165/js/detheme.js:7:2907)
    at O (http://localhost:51165/js/webflow.js:7:2897)
    at Object.t.each.t.forEach (http://localhost:51165/js/webflow.js:38:553)
    at HTMLDocument.r.ready (http://localhost:51165/js/webflow.js:7:3244)
    at l (https://d1tdp7z6w94jbb.cloudfront.net/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2:29375)
    at c (https://d1tdp7z6w94jbb.cloudfront.net/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2:29677) undefined:

Comment: I don't understand why you want to "load jquery twice". On a page we only load jquery only once. First we load jquery then, we load other scripts depending on jquery.

Comment: I have two jquery blocks in my html page. Each animated block load his own jquery file.

Comment: We would need to see the js files you include to be sure. But a important question is: Why would you do this. jQuery is meant to be inserted once and will be available virtually everywhere. [noConflict Mode](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) could be a start to solve this. **But neither me nor the jQuery documentation recommends to load jQuery twice.**

Comment: I think it's better to show what you are trying to do in code, because it seems you have no need to start jQuery twice, but instead you are going for a misleading way.

Comment: Now, I load jquery one time, but always the same error. I think there is some conflicts into **webflow.js** and **detheme.js**

Comment: Show us the code, you only show the error

Comment: webflow.js : https://js.do/lesafir/410381

Comment: detheme.js : https://js.do/lesafir/410382

Comment: Where have you included these 3 files?

Comment: Make sure that webflow.js is included exact above </body> tag. and other includes should be above it.

Comment: <html>
<head>
...
</head>
<html>
<body>
.....
<script src="https://d1tdp7z6w94jbb.cloudfront.net/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="js/detheme.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/webflow.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Please  can you help me :(